# Storing sensitive data within the source of compiled programs

Tags: c, libcurl, decompiling

In [this](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/imap-ssl.html) example usage of libcurl the program will "log in" to an IMAP server using a user and secret password string, stored in two separate strings within the source, for the sake of brevity. Most real email clients (gnus, mutt) read from a plain text config file or an encrypted file, if I were to compile the example file with a real username and secret key, would it be possible to decompile the binary produced to parse the private key? I imagine a private key entered into a macro before compilation is more secure than reading a config file after compiling, is this understanding correct?

Comment: If you use a macro then the private key is baked into the executable. You wouldn't necessarily need to decompile the executable, but someone with some know-how could read it out. Loading a private key at runtime solves that issue.

Comment: Since they are string literals you wouldn't even need to decompile it. https://linux.die.net/man/1/strings would easily print them.

Answer (score 2):

If the username and secret are strings and are simply included in the source, they can be extracted from the binary executable without even decompiling. See the `strings` command. You can take steps to include the username and secret in the source such that they are not readily findable by `strings` (e.g., by XORing the string with some other bit pattern in the program before adding it, then XORing in the executable to recover the original). This is "security through obscurity," however, and is not recommended.

Placing the username and secret in a configuration file lets you use the system's file permissions so that people using the binary may not necessarily have permission to read the file. You may also be able to set up a PKI authentication arrangement, or possibly use Kerberos key authorization.

The amount of effort to go to depends on the value of what you're trying to protect.

Comment: In this vain, couldn't the compiled binary (and for extra security the source) have its permissions modified by the user that compiled it so that only (s)he can access it? ie. on linux it would mean creating a group for personal binaries with only the current user, and using ```chmod 640``` on it.

Comment: @BithovVinu Yes, but then any privileged user (sudo) can see the password. Also, then only the user can execute the program -- and the user presumably already knows the username and secret, so you wouldn't need to include them in the binary unless you were making the application available to other people.

Comment: I created a new group only my custom user was in - changed the permissions accordingly. When I switched to root (using su) I tried to run the executable and had permission denied - I created an entirely different group to sudo.